# Choppy CATextLayer animation: fontSize + position concurrently

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I need to animate a `CATextLayer`'s `bounds.size.height`, `position`, and `fontSize`. When I add them to a `CAAnimationGroup`, the text jitters during the animation, just like this:

https://youtu.be/HfC1ZX-pbyM

The jittering of the text's tracking values (spacing between characters) seems to occur while animating `fontSize` with `bounds.size.height` AND/OR `position`. I've isolated `fontSize`, and it performs well on its own.

How can I prevent the text from jittering in `CATextLayer` if I animate bounds and font size at the same time?

---

**EDIT**

I've moved on from animating `bounds`. Now, I only care about `fontSize` + `position`. Here are two videos showing the difference.

`fontSize` only (smooth): https://youtu.be/FDPPGF_FzLI

`fontSize` + `position` (jittery): https://youtu.be/3rFTsp7wBzk

Here is the code for that.

```
    let startFontSize: CGFloat = 16
    let endFontSize: CGFloat = 30

    let startPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 40, y: 100)
    let endPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 20, y: 175)

    // Initialize the layer

    textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.string = "Hello how are you?"
    textLayer.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: startFontSize, weight: UIFont.Weight.semibold)
    textLayer.fontSize = startFontSize
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentLeft
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    textLayer.isWrapped = true
    textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    textLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    textLayer.position = startPosition
    textLayer.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 450, height: 50)
    view.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)

    // Animate

    let damping: CGFloat = 20
    let mass: CGFloat = 1.2

    var animations = [CASpringAnimation]()

    let fontSizeAnim = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "fontSize")           
    fontSizeAnim.fromValue = startFontSize
    fontSizeAnim.toValue = endFontSize
    fontSizeAnim.damping = damping
    fontSizeAnim.mass = mass
    fontSizeAnim.duration = fontSizeAnim.settlingDuration
    animations.append(fontSizeAnim)

    let positionAnim = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    positionAnim.fromValue = textLayer.position.y
    positionAnim.toValue = endPosition.y
    positionAnim.damping = damping
    positionAnim.mass = mass
    positionAnim.duration = positionAnim.settlingDuration
    animations.append(positionAnim)

    let animGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animGroup.animations = animations
    animGroup.duration = fontSizeAnim.settlingDuration
    animGroup.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
    animGroup.autoreverses = true
    textLayer.add(animGroup, forKey: nil)
```

My device is running iOS 11.0.

---

**EDIT 2**

I've broken down each animation (`fontSize` only, and `fontSize` + `position`) frame-by-frame. In each video, I'm progressing 1 frame at a time.

In the `fontSize` only video (https://youtu.be/DZw2pMjDcl8), **each frame** yields an increase in `fontSize`, so there's no choppiness.

In the `fontSize` + `position` video (https://youtu.be/_idWte92F38), **`position` is updated in every frame, but not `fontSize`**. There is only an increase in `fontSize` in 60% of frames, meaning that `fontSize` isn't animating in sync with `position`, causing the perceived chopping.

So maybe the right question is: why does `fontSize` animate in each frame when it's the only animation added to a layer, but not when added as part of `CAAnimationGroup` in conjunction with the `position` animation?

Comment: Have tried to use separate layers for text and background? You can animate them separately.

Comment: What do you mean by "background"? As in a `UIView` wrapper containing the layer, added to a superview?

Comment: I mean the area (e. g. the blue colored square in your video). If it's transparent, you shouldn't animate the bounds. Just set the text layer to the maximal possible size.

Comment: 1) Well, the blue square is the `backgroundColor` of the `CATextLayer` itself, so the "text" and "background" are parts of the same layer. You're right about `bounds`; I've moved on from trying it. 2) My problem now is with `position`. And for that, I'm stumped. I feel like the system font's tracking values are fighting the animation, since each `pointSize` has its own value and must redraw itself as it resizes.

Comment: It looks more of an issue with the time durations rather than any problem with the font. The animation timeline could be confusing in your case where you're apply duration on individual animations too. I would recommend trying again with removing individual durations and just using the animation group's duration. You can do ```[animGroup.animations valueForKeyPath:@"@max.endTime"]``` to get the maximum duration too. Correct me if i'm wrong here.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulSubhan unfortunately, removing individual `CASpringAnimation` durations has no effect. `CAAnimationGroup().duration` also doesn't scale its animations to fit; rather, it clips. So it doesn't affect value interpolation.

Comment: @chicobermuda What's the value of startSize?

Comment: Are you really stuck on this such that you need a workaround, no matter how it's accomplished? I took macmoonshine's suggestion to be similar to my approach. Give your CATextLayer a new parent layer that is simply a vanilla CALayer. Animate separately, by putting the position animation on the parent layer, while leaving the fontSize animating on the text.

Comment: @Bobjt yeah I've tried this method already. It's just as choppy as before.

Comment: This needs to be run on device, by the way. My code runs pretty smoothly in a playground.

Answer (score 7):

Apple DTS believes this issue is a bug. A report has been filed.

In the meantime, I'll be using `CADisplayLink` to synchronize the redrawing of `CATextLayer.fontSize` to the refresh rate of the device, which will redraw the layer with the appropriate `fontSize` in each frame.

---

**Edit**

After tinkering with `CADisplayLink` for a day or so, drawing to the correct `fontSize` proved difficult, especially when paired with a custom timing function. So, I'm giving up on `CATextLayer` altogether and going back to `UILabel`.

In WWDC '17's [Advanced Animations with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/?time=1205), Apple recommends "view morphing" to animate between two label states — that is, the translation, scaling, and opacity blending of two views. `UIViewPropertyAnimator` provides a lot of flexibility for this, like blending multiple timing functions and scrubbing. View morphing is also useful for transitioning between 2 `text` values without having to fade out the text representation, changing `text`, and fading back in.

I do hope Apple can beef up `CATextLayer` support for non-interactive animations, as I'd prefer using one view to animate the same text representation.